# Get Image Absolute URL From Some Node in HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, html, redirect, html-agility-pack, relative-url

I want fetch some webpage from internet, and get absolute URLs of some images on the page by using HtmlAgilityPack in C#.

The problem is...

The website will first *redirect* the URL to some other one, and then the `src` attribute in the `<img>` tag is *related URL*.

---

Currently, I have some codes like this:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlDocument webpageDocument = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://xyz.example.com/");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = webpageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
String url = nodes[0].Attributes["src"].Value.ToString();
```

Above codes fetch a webpage from the given example url, and get some `<img>` element from the DOM tree, and get `src` attribute of it.

It works if the `<img>` has absolute url. But unfortunately the website I want to handle give me a related URI (e.g. `/img/01.png`). I need the absolute URL so that I can do more options about the image.

So, I need to know what URL is the *base URL* for given `src`, but failed. Or, in another word, I don't know how to get the *location* of the webpage after *redirect*.

---

Server side is not mine (I have no control to it).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [ResponseUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri(v=vs.110).aspx) and to avoid second call give html agility parser the string with the content of the page instead.